# JMETER: How to add value from CSV file in Json Extractor?

Tags: json, jmeter, json-extract

I want to pass value from my csv file in json extractor but it's not working.
I have tried like **[?(@.name == '${UserName}')].id** but when i am simply writing Username without taking it from CSV then it is working.

Comment: You are using this correctly. Just make sure you have the variable name correctly picked **UserName** and also the JSON Expression should be like **$..[?(@.name == '${UserName}')]**

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your **UserName** variable exists and has the anticipated value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) combination

[image]

As long as the associated [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) exists you should be able to use it in the JSON Extractor